# gedit Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused in ubuntu WSL

Tags: networking, apt, gedit, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed WSL with ubuntu 18.04 . I want to use gedit which I have already  installed . The problem is that whenever I run a command with gedit I get

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
(gedit:14177): Gtk-WARNING **: 20:09:43.143: cannot open display: 0:0
```

My issue is the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60284542/wsl-gedit-unable-to-init-server-could-not-connect-connection-refused where I have followed the instructions but got the same result . In order I tried :

sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get update
export DISPLAY=0:0
gedit test.tcl //error hits

I have already downloaded and opened Xming and then tried the above commands and got same error

I also tried reverting back to WSL 1 from WSL 2 and it doesn't seem to me that the version has changed

[image]

I would apreciate your help

Comment: The accepted answer on that question only works for WSL1. To convert your image, you must use `wsl --set-version Ubuntu-18.04 1`. The `--set-default-version` command that you tried only changes the default version for instances you create in the future.